# Postgres and Docker Compose; password authentication fails and role 'postgres' does not exist. Cannot connect from pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

I have a docker-compose that brings up the psql database as below, currently I'm trying to connect to it with pgAdmin4 (not in a docker container) and be able to view it. I've been having trouble authenticating with the DB and I don't understand why.

**docker-compose**

```
version: "3"

services:
  # nginx and server also have an override, but not important for this q.
  nginx:
    ports:
      - 1234:80
      - 1235:443
  server:
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - 3001:3001 # app server port
      - 9230:9230 # debugging port
    env_file: .env
    command: yarn dev
    volumes:
      # Mirror local code but not node_modules
      - /server/node_modules/
      - ./server:/server
  
  database:
    container_name: column-db
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres # The PostgreSQL user (useful to connect to the database)
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root # The PostgreSQL password (useful to connect to the database)
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres # The PostgreSQL default database (automatically created at first launch)
    volumes:
      - ./db-data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

I do `docker-compose up` then check the logs, and it says that it is ready for connections. I go to pgAdmin and enter the following:
[image: first screen]

[image: second screen]

where password is `root`. I then get this error:

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I check the docker logs and I see

```
DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, according to the docs the super user should be created with those specifications. Am I missing something? Been banging my head against this for an hour now. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I also have tried going into the docker container and checking postgres, but it says I can't run it in root mode

Comment: Also keep seeing this error under it as well `Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"`

Comment: Since you are using a mapped volume, the database is only created if that volume is empty.  Otherwise it reuses the database it finds there.  If that database was created under a different setting of POSTGRES_USER, then it won't have the user you are expecting.

Comment: @jjanes thanks for the reply! I’m afk right now but will try that out when I get back, I think this will help since the volume part is the only difference from the command line docker command. That’s what I get for following docker-compose instructions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@jjanes solved it in a comment, I had used a mapped volume and never properly set up the db. Removed the volume and we're good to go.

Comment: Thanks Its solved after creating new volume :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is @jjanes's comment:

Since you are using a mapped volume, the database is only created if that volume is empty. Otherwise, it reuses the database it finds there. If that database was created under a different setting of POSTGRES_USER, then it won't have the user you are expecting.

There are two ways to fix this:

Modify the configuration at the bottom of the pg_hba.conf file:

Change:

```html
# host all all all scram-sha-256
 host all all all md5
```

Alternatively, when starting the Docker container, modify the configuration by adding:

```html
POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS="--auth-host=scram-sha-256"
```

This makes the generated passwords default to using scram-sha-256 encryption for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a permissions issue.
The owner and group of the directory was changed by mistake.
I changed it back to my user (lcompare) and group (lcompare) and it worked.

```
sudo chown lcompare:lcompare db
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for mine five cents. I've struggled with the same issue, on the docker image postgres:14.7-alpine. Although clear a volume didn't help. But I've noticed that comment ports in the docker-compose.yaml for postgres service and clear volume helps me. Perhaps it's issue in postgres database initialization logic.

```
    # ports:
    #  - 5432:5432
```

The ports only needs if you try to open port 5432 on the host for internal application connection it's doesn't necessary.